# JSP JSTL and other directives are not recognized

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, directive, taglib

After going through numerous previously answered posts, I'm still unable to find solution for the issue I'm facing. In my JSP, none of the directives are working. I'm primarily focused to get <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%> to work.

I have also checked include directive and <%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>  . JSP is indicating errors for all of these directives. I have added following dependency to my pom.xml file
        
            jstl
            jstl
            1.2
        
Also, downloaded jstl1.2, taglibs-standard-impl-1.2.5 jars to my WEB-INF/lib folder, but nothing seems to work.

My web.xml starts with:

```
< ?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
< web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">
```

What other places do I need to check so that I can use JSTL core taglib?

Error being indicated:

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - Invalid text string (<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %> <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%> ).
    - Invalid character used in text string (<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %> <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/
     jsp/jstl/core"%> ).
```

Thanks in advance,